# In a react-native android project,How to copy a folder from assets to the DocumentDirectoryPath?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs, document-directory

I am using a react-native project in which,I want to copy the contents of a certain folder in assets inside android to  RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath. How can this be performed?

I have used the attribute copyFileAssets().

```
 copyfile() {
    RNFS.copyFileAssets('/ICF-Package', RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/ICFPackage').then((result) => console.log('DONE')).catch((error) => console.log(error, 'ERROR'));
  };

  I'm getting the following error:
```

Error: Asset '/ICF-Package' could not be opened

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. However, it looks like `/ICF-Package` is a folder or something, but not a file. `copyFileAssets` can only copy files, but no folders (and its content)